# Postal.AspNetCore create EmailService outside of ASP.NET request

Tags: razorengine, postal

I have an MVC application (.net 4.7.2) that sends emails using Hangfire and Postal. I am converting this application to .Net Core, and I try to use Postal.AspNetCore. I need to create EmailService outside of ASP.NET request, EmailService is created in abstract class.

In the old project we used Postal.Mvc5 and we created EmailService using FileSystemRazorViewEngine .

Could you share an example how to create EmailService using Postal.AspNetCore.
Constructor is EmailService(IEmailViewRender emailViewRenderer, IEmailParser emailParser ...).
How do I create emailViewRenderer and emailParser that are required.